# Remove SSN (Social Security Number) from a String in SQL

Tags: sql-server, regex

I have a string in a MS 2000 SQL db and need to remove just the SSN using the select satement. I don't have the option of using an external app. The other fun part is that the locaton of the SSN is not always the same.

```
[B-Day][First Name][SSN][POB]
12121970John123-45-6789Las Vages
```

Or

```
[B-Day][First Name][Last Name][SSN][POB]
12121970JohnDoe123-45-6789Las Vages
```

I need RegEx of the SQL variety!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT substring(a, 1, PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]-%', a) - 3)  
+ substring(a, PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]-%', a) + 9, 100) FROM myTable
```

myTable is the table, "a" is the name of the column.

EDIT: Ofcourse there is some assumption regarding social security number format.
Also, I have added an arbitrary number 100 to pick the string to the end. You can increase it if your string is more than that.

Comment: I had to change things a little but it got me started. Thanks!

SELECT substring(a, 1, PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]-%', a) - 1) + 
substring(a, PatIndex('%-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', a) + 5, 100)
FROM testTable

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to the server itself, [here is an article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/regular-expressions-in-t-sql) which describes how to add a Regex function using VBScript to MSSQL 2000. From there the regex for matching a SSN is quite simple (`[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}`). You may need to expand the function provided in the article to support replacing as well as matching.

Comment: This is good answer and is more generic. But I don't have access to the server in this case. Thanks!